# UWP KeyRoutedEventArgs.handled Does Not Cancel Backspace Key

Tags: c#, events, uwp, event-handling

Is there a way to cancel the backspace key with a `KeyDownEvent` in UWP?  This event uses `KeyRoutedEventArgs`, so there is no `SuppressKeyPress` function.

`event.Handled = true` does not help; it only stops the event from being called multiple times in quick succession from the same key press.

Does such a function exist?

Comment: e.Handled = true should work, there must be something else causing the issue, can you please post complete code for further help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a TextBox defined like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

And in the KeyDown-event if you just set Handled = true every time, user can't enter anything:

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But as you mentioned, if you check for Back-key and set the Handled = true, it doesn't work: User is still able to use backspace. So this doesn't work.

```
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

If you debug the code you can see that the character is already gone when the eventhandler is executed. You have to work around this, using other events. Here's one option:

XAML:

```
    <TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" KeyUp="TextBox_KeyUp"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    private string currentText;
    private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentText))
                return;

            ((TextBox)sender).Text = currentText;
            ((TextBox)sender).SelectionStart = currentText.Length;
            ((TextBox)sender).SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }

    private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentText = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
```

Comment: That worked well.  Thanks.  However, is there a way to save the cursor location?  I tried adding a selection changed function and a new variable similar to the way you set up `currentText`, but it always snapped back.